# Which is the correct answer from the following options-

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such  that the subsequences $(x_{2n})$  &$(x_{3n})$ converge to limits $K$ and $L$ respectively.Then-

- $(x_{n})$ always converges.
- If  $K=L$,then $(x_n)$ converges.
- $(x_n)$ may not converge,but $K=L$.
- it is possible to have $K \neq L.$

This question has been asked in ISI-2017 entrance exam.Last two options are correct but i'm not able to justify it.Moreover,i'm not getting how to discard first two options.

Also please suggest me some reference from where i can get these kind of problems.

Any kind of hint or help or suggestions are heartly welcome!!

Comment: How can the two last options be correct if they contradict each other in *at least* one point? In the third option we *decide that* $\;K=L\;$, whereas in the 4th one we decide that $\;K\neq L\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio:There is a misprinting in the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{3n})$ share a common infinite subsequence, namely $(x_{6n})$.

Any infinite subsequence of a convergent sequence converges, and moreover, converges to the same limit as the full sequence.

It follows that $K=L$.

To see that the sequence $(x_n)$ need not converge, consider the sequence defined by
$$x_n = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if}\;n\;\text{is relatively prime to $6$}\\[4pt]
0 &\text{otherwise}\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can discard the first two options by looking at $x_p$ for prime values of $p$

---

Also, it is not true that the last two options are correct, since the last two options clearly contradict each other (one claiming $K=L$ is always true, the other saying $K\neq L$ is possible).

In fact, only the third option is true, and proving $K=L$ is most efficient by looking at the limit of $x_{6n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation*}
x_n = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } 2 \text{ or } 3 \text{ divides } n \\
n &\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
For this sequence, we have $K = L = 0$, but $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not bounded, and therefore does not converge. So both options 1 and 2 are false.

Suppose that $K \neq L$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\varepsilon < ( K - L ) / 3$. From the convergence of $(x_{2n})$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $| L - x_{2n} | < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N_1$. Similarly, from the convergence of $(x_{3n})$, there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $| K - x_{3n} | < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N_2$. Let $N = \max \{ N_1, N_2 \}$. The term $x_{6N}$ appears both in $(x_{2n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (at index $3N$) and in $(x_{3n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (at index $2N$), and both $2N$ and $3N$ are greater than $N$. Therefore we must have $| x_{6N} - L | < \varepsilon$ and $| x_{6N} - K | < \varepsilon$. This leads to $| K - L | \leq | K - x_{6N} | + | x_{6N} - L | < 2 \varepsilon \leq 2 / 3 \cdot ( K - L )$, which is absurd. So we must have $K = L$. Option 3 is then true, and option 4 false.

Comment: Try to use spaces and spacing more generously. Your last parraph is very hard to read, not to mention to follow. Also use complete fractions, like \frac23 to write $\;\frac23\;$ , instead of merely 2/3 which, in the lines' density, can get lost. You are also condensing info from the other two, much earlier, answers.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I will be more careful with spacing and fractions. Also, there were no answers yet when I started writing mine, and missed the small line saying "new answers to this questions" when I posted...